# Pulling Entries by Parent Category

Tags: categories

It seems pretty tedious to have to type in all the Category Ids to list all parent & children entries.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel ="channel_name" category="17|4|1|5|13|9|14|25|2|7|24|3|6|28"     }
```

Is there more maintainable way to do this?

Comment: Need a bit more info here. Are all categories from the same category group or different groups?

Comment: From the same category group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [Auto-Assign Category Parents](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#auto-assign-category-parents) is enabled, you can list just the parents.